# right group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Wikipedia says

> 'The difference between left and right actions is in the order in which a product like $gh$ acts on $x$. For a left action $h$ acts first and is followed by $g$, while for a right action $g$ acts first and is followed by $h$. Because of the formula $(gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$, one can construct a left action from a right action by composing with the inverse operation of the group.'

I am struggling with the part where it says 'Because of the formula $(gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$, one can construct a left action from a right action by composing with the inverse operation of the group.''

How can you construct left action from right action? if right action is $(g,x) \rightarrow xg$
any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you didn't invert and you tried to turn $x \mapsto xg$ into a left-action then you'd get into trouble, because (if say $g \star x = xg$) then you'd have
$$g \star (h \star x) = (xh)g = x(hg) = (hg) \star x \ne (gh) \star x$$
however if you had $g \star x = xg^{-1}$ then you'd have
$$g \star (h \star x) = (xh^{-1})g^{-1} = x(h^{-1}g^{-1}) = x(gh)^{-1} = (gh) \star x$$
so everything's dandy.

**Summary:**

If $x \mapsto gx$ is a left action then $x \mapsto xg^{-1}$ is a right action.

If $x \mapsto xg$ is a right action then $x \mapsto g^{-1}x$ is a left action.

The idea is that inversion reverses the order of composition, so gives you right actions from left action and left actions from right actions.

Comment: I think that you made mistake in your summary section. If $x \mapsto g.x$ is a left group action then we should have $x \mapsto g^{-1}.x$ is a right group action because in that case you don't know how to act $g^{-1}$ from the right of $x$ as $(.)$ is given to be a left group action. Similarly if $x \mapsto x.g$ is a right group action then $x \mapsto x.g^{-1}$ is a left group action. Am I doing any mistake? If so please rectify me.

Comment: @mathmaniac. With any left action you can _define_ a right action in a canonical way as Clive did which exactly adress the question.