# What is the description of the (local) sections of the associated vector bundle of a principal bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

I was reading the following lecture notes: [Lecture on Connections](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/h.b.posthuma/TIP2019/Lecture5-2019.pdf) (p. 1-2). I am going to paraphrase it a bit, but it said the following

> Let $\pi \colon P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $V$ be a representation of $G$. The **associated vector bundle** is the vector bundle is given by $E(V) := (P \times V)/G$.

From here the author argued that this construction is abstract, but that the (local) sections have concrete descriptions. They are given by the maps $s: P \to V$ for which 
$$
s(pg) = g \cdot s(p)
$$
for all $g \in G$ and $p \in P$. I have two questions:

1. How is $E(V) = (P \times V)/G$ exactly defined? Is it that $$(p, v) \sim (g p, g^{-1} \cdot v) \quad \text{or} \quad (p,v) \sim (gp, g \cdot v)?$$ According to [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedVectorBundle.html), it should be the former, but why do we choose to define it that way exactly?
2. How do the maps $s: P \to V$ give information on the sections of $E(V)$? Shouldn't sections of $E(V)$ be of the form $$ \hat s: M \to E(V)? $$

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the $G$-equivariant maps $s: P \to V$, the sections of $E(V)$ are then $\hat s: M \to E(V)$ where ${\hat s(x) := (p, s(p))}$ for some $p \in \pi_{E(V)}^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Is $(gp,v)\sim(p,gv)$? or $(p,g^{-1}v)$. Because there is a precise definition of G-equivariant map and somehow I see there's a problem with the $g^{-1}$ pulling out rather than g.

Comment: I believe the answer with g^{-1} is the correct one. That is because you have defined a right action on the fibres of a principal bundle. Given a right action $p \mapsto pg$ on a set, you can naturally define a left-action by $p \mapsto g^{-1} p$. You can see this post for a more lengthy discussion on this (in a general setting): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338867/379250